# Javascript Phone number auto convert is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript code like below

```
function mask(eventVal,val){
    var len = val.value.length;
    var key = whichKey(eventVal);
    if(key>47 && key<58)
    {   
        if( len==0 )val.value=val.value+'('
        else if( len==4 )val.value=val.value+') '
        else if(len==9 )val.value=val.value+'-'
        else val.value=val.value;
    }
    else{
        val.value = val.value.replace(/[^0-9-]/,'')
        val.value = val.value.replace('--','-')
    }
}

function whichKey(eventVal) {
    var code;
    if (!eventVal) var eventVal = window.event;
    if (eventVal.keyCode) code = eventVal.keyCode;
    else if (eventVal.which) code = eventVal.which;
    return code;
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="PhoneNumber" id="PhoneNumber" value="" onkeydown="mask(event,this)"/>
```

It is working fine when I am typing phone number like 1234567890 is automatically converting into (123) 456-7890 when I am trying to remove value like remove 0 from the end then formatting is getting ruined completely. like 123) 456-789 and even it is getting ruined when I am click any other place. Can Any one help me to fix it?

Comment: The problem is that backspace and other non-numeric characters will go down your `else` path which does a replace to remove the parentheses that you added previously. Besides that you might like to use `onkeyup` rather than `onkeydown` so that you are working with the value _after_ whatever character was just typed. In any case, here's a demo for people to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/weSvU/

Comment: P.S. Note also that because you are using _key_ codes rather than _character_ codes in your `if` test it won't work on characters entered via the numeric keypad, and (on my country's keyboard) 1 and ! have the same keycode, 2 and @ have the same keycode, and so forth. I'd suggest you do the processing `onblur` so that you don't have to deal with the user trying to edit in the middle of the string and so forth. When they leave the field just reformat the whole string...

Comment: Your code is not working

Comment: The fiddle I posted was _your_ code, there for people to play. Here's something I came up with that works a bit better: http://jsfiddle.net/weSvU/1/ (much shorter code, but still doesn't really deal with the user editing a previously entered value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this script..

```
<script language="javascript">
var zChar = new Array(' ', '(', ')', '-', '.');
var maxphonelength = 14;
var phonevalue1;
var phonevalue2;
var cursorposition;
function ParseForNumber1(object){
  phonevalue1 = ParseChar(object.value, zChar);
}
function ParseForNumber2(object){
  phonevalue2 = ParseChar(object.value, zChar);
}
function up(object,e) { 
  if(e){ 
    e = e 
  } else {
    e = window.event 
  } 
  if(e.which){ 
    var keycode = e.which 
  } else {
    var keycode = e.keyCode 
  }
  ParseForNumber1(object)
  if(keycode >= 48){
    ValidatePhone(object)
  }
}
function down(object,e) { 
  if(e){ 
    e = e 
  } else {
    e = window.event 
  } 
  if(e.which){ 
    var keycode = e.which 
  } else {
    var keycode = e.keyCode 
  }
  ParseForNumber2(object)
} 
function GetCursorPosition(){
  var t1 = phonevalue1;
  var t2 = phonevalue2;
  var bool = false
  for (i=0; i<t1.length; i++)
  {
    if (t1.substring(i,1) != t2.substring(i,1)) {
      if(!bool) {
        cursorposition=i
        window.status=cursorposition
        bool=true
      }
    }
  }
}
function ValidatePhone(object){
  var p = phonevalue1
  p = p.replace(/[^\d]*/gi,"")
  if (p.length < 3) {
    object.value=p
  } else if(p.length==3){
    pp=p;
    d4=p.indexOf('(')
    d5=p.indexOf(')')
    if(d4==-1){
      pp="("+pp;
    }
    if(d5==-1){
      pp=pp+")";
    }
    object.value = pp;
  } else if(p.length>3 && p.length < 7){
    p ="(" + p; 
    l30=p.length;
    p30=p.substring(0,4);
    p30=p30+") " 
    p31=p.substring(4,l30);
    pp=p30+p31;
    object.value = pp; 
  } else if(p.length >= 7){
    p ="(" + p; 
    l30=p.length;
    p30=p.substring(0,4);
    p30=p30+") " 

    p31=p.substring(4,l30);
    pp=p30+p31;

    l40 = pp.length;
    p40 = pp.substring(0,9);
    p40 = p40 + "-"

    p41 = pp.substring(9,l40);
    ppp = p40 + p41;

    object.value = ppp.substring(0, maxphonelength);
  }
  GetCursorPosition()
  if(cursorposition >= 0){
    if (cursorposition == 0) {
      cursorposition = 2
    } else if (cursorposition <= 2) {
      cursorposition = cursorposition + 1
    } else if (cursorposition <= 4) {
      cursorposition = cursorposition + 3
    } else if (cursorposition == 5) {
      cursorposition = cursorposition + 3
    } else if (cursorposition == 6) { 
      cursorposition = cursorposition + 3 
    } else if (cursorposition == 7) { 
      cursorposition = cursorposition + 4 
    } else if (cursorposition == 8) { 
      cursorposition = cursorposition + 4
      e1=object.value.indexOf(')')
      e2=object.value.indexOf('-')
      if (e1>-1 && e2>-1){
        if (e2-e1 == 4) {
          cursorposition = cursorposition - 1
        }
      }
    } else if (cursorposition == 9) {
      cursorposition = cursorposition + 4
    } else if (cursorposition < 11) {
      cursorposition = cursorposition + 3
    } else if (cursorposition == 11) {
      cursorposition = cursorposition + 1
    } else if (cursorposition == 12) {
      cursorposition = cursorposition + 1
    } else if (cursorposition >= 13) {
      cursorposition = cursorposition
    }

    var txtRange = object.createTextRange();
    txtRange.moveStart( "character", cursorposition);
    txtRange.moveEnd( "character", cursorposition - object.value.length);
    txtRange.select();
  }

}

function ParseChar(sStr, sChar)
{
  if (sChar.length == null) 
  {
    zChar = new Array(sChar);
  }
    else zChar = sChar;
  for (i=0; i<zChar.length; i++)
  {
    sNewStr = "";
    var iStart = 0;
    var iEnd = sStr.indexOf(sChar[i]);
    while (iEnd != -1)
    {
      sNewStr += sStr.substring(iStart, iEnd);
      iStart = iEnd + 1;
      iEnd = sStr.indexOf(sChar[i], iStart);
    }
    sNewStr += sStr.substring(sStr.lastIndexOf(sChar[i]) + 1, sStr.length);
    sStr = sNewStr;
  }
  return sNewStr;
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="txtInput" onkeydown="javascript:down(this,event);" onkeyup="javascript:up(this,event);">
```

Comment: That doesn't work if you edit a value previously entered, e.g., if you delete the numbers already between the parentheses. At least, it didn't work in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/pZKPS/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to replace your last digit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fnc()
{

    str=document.getElementById("atext").value;
    x=(str.match(pattern));
    if(x!="")
    {str=str.replace(/[0-9]$/g,'')}
    alert(str);
}

</script>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="atext">
  <input type="button" onClick="fnc()">
</body>
```